# Running app inside Docker as non-root user

Tags: node.js, docker, lxc

After [yesterday's news of Shocker](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7909622), it seems like apps inside a Docker container should not be run as root.  I tried to update my `Dockerfile` to create an app user however changing permissions on app files (while still root) doesn't seem to work.  I'm guessing this is because some LXC permission is not being granted to the root user maybe?

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
# Node.js app Docker file

FROM dockerfile/nodejs
MAINTAINER Thom Nichols "thom@thomnichols.org"

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash node

ADD . /data
# This next line doesn't seem to have any effect:
RUN chown -R node /data 

ENV HOME /home/node
USER node

RUN cd /data && npm install

EXPOSE 8888

WORKDIR /data

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Pretty straightforward, but when I `ls -l` everything is still owned by root:

```
[ node@ed7ae33e76e1:/data {docker-nonroot-user} ]$ ls -l /data
total 64K
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  383 Jun 18 20:32 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  862 Jun 18 16:23 Gruntfile.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K Jun 18 15:48 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K May 30 14:24 assets/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  416 Jun  3 14:22 bower.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  930 May 30 01:50 config.js
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Jun 18 16:08 lib/
drwxr-xr-x 42 root root 4.0K Jun 18 16:04 node_modules/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2.0K Jun 18 16:04 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  118 May 30 18:35 server.js
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K May 30 02:17 static/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Jun 18 20:13 test/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Jun  3 17:38 views/
```

---

[My updated dockerfile works great](https://gist.github.com/thom-nic/5e561e800cbc0f71555c) thanks to @creak's clarification of how volumes work.  Once the initial files are `chown`ed, `npm install` is run as the non-root user.  And thanks to a `postinstall` hook, npm runs `bower install && grunt assets` which takes care of the remaining install steps and avoids any need to `npm install -g` any node cli tools like bower, grunt or coffeescript.

Comment: Just curious, are you certain that `node` user is getting created?

Comment: @a.m. yes the user is definitely created.  I when I run `docker run -it myimage /bin/bash` and run `whoami` I'm logged in as `node` which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky, it is actually due to the image you start from.

If you [look at the source](https://github.com/dockerfile/nodejs/blob/master/Dockerfile), you notice that `/data/` is a volume. So everything you do in the `Dockerfile` will be discarded and overridden at runtime by the volume that gets mounted then.

You can chown at runtime by changing your CMD to something like `CMD chown -R node /data && npm start`.

Comment: Interesting!  I guess I didn't/ don't completely grok the volume concept (I will start reading up) nor the distinction between runtime and build time.

Comment: Unfortunately the `CMD chown...` won't work because that will be run as the `node` user who obv doesn't have permission to change permissions of files owned by `root`. 

I'm starting to wonder if it's OK if the source code is not writable at runtime so long as the app has access to a writable location for things like logs & runtime-compiled files.  

Is is possible to create a volume not owned by root at runtime?

Comment: Not that I know of. An alternative would be not to use USER node, keep root and start npm with `su node -c "npm start"`. But depending on your need it should be OK to run as read only as long as you have access to a writable directory.

Comment: So I'm going to accept this as the correct answer because you were spot on about the issue being `/data` as a volume.  If I change that directory to anything else, `/opt/foobar` or `/home/node/app`, then `chown` works fine as part of the build.  Also I've confirmed that `chown`-ing a volume in a running container also appears to work.  I think the easiest solution is to not use a volume for the app sources.  I updated my resulting Dockerfile here: https://gist.github.com/thom-nic/5e561e800cbc0f71555c

Answer (score 26):

Check this post: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/08/29/docker-non-root.html In [rultor.com](http://www.rultor.com) we run all builds in their own Docker containers. And every time before running the scripts inside the container, we switch to a non-root user. This is how:

```
adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' r
adduser r sudo
echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
su -m r -c /home/r/script.sh
```

`r` is the user we're using.

Comment: You may have to explicitly create the user's home directory with: `adduser -m --disabled-password --gecos '' r`

Comment: Systems that are Red Hat-based, such as Fedora and CentOS, you have to do this differently.

Answer (score 18):

Update 2015-09-28

I have noticed this post getting a bit of attention.  A word of advice for anyone who is potentially interested in doing something like this.  I would try to use Python or another language as a wrapper for your script executions.  Doing native bash scripts I had problems when trying to pass through a variety of arguments to my containers.  Specifically there was issues with the interpretation/escaping of " and ' characters by the shell.

---

I was needing to change the user for a slightly different reason.

I created a *docker image* housing a full featured install of *ImageMagick* and *Ffmpeg* with a desire that I could do transformations on images/videos within my host OS.  My problem was that these are command line tools, so it is slightly trickier to execute them via docker and then get the results back into the host OS.  I managed to allow for this by mounting a docker volume.  This seemed to work okay except that the image/video output was coming out as being owned by *root* (i.e. the user the docker container was running as), rather than the user whom executed the command.

I looked at the approach that @François Zaninotto mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25765407/350933) (you can see the full make script [here](https://github.com/marmelab/make-docker-command/blob/master/Makefile)). It was really cool, but I preferred the option of creating a bash shell script that I would then register on my path.  I took some of the concepts from the Makefile approach (specifically the user/group creation) and then I created the shell script.

Here is an example of my *dockermagick* shell script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

### VARIABLES

DOCKER_IMAGE='acleancoder/imagemagick-full:latest'
CONTAINER_USERNAME='dummy'
CONTAINER_GROUPNAME='dummy'
HOMEDIR='/home/'$CONTAINER_USERNAME
GROUP_ID=$(id -g)
USER_ID=$(id -u)

### FUNCTIONS

create_user_cmd()
{
  echo \
    groupadd -f -g $GROUP_ID $CONTAINER_GROUPNAME '&&' \
    useradd -u $USER_ID -g $CONTAINER_GROUPNAME $CONTAINER_USERNAME '&&' \
    mkdir --parent $HOMEDIR '&&' \
    chown -R $CONTAINER_USERNAME:$CONTAINER_GROUPNAME $HOMEDIR
}

execute_as_cmd()
{
  echo \
    sudo -u $CONTAINER_USERNAME HOME=$HOMEDIR
}

full_container_cmd()
{
  echo "'$(create_user_cmd) && $(execute_as_cmd) $@'"
}

### MAIN

eval docker run \
    --rm=true \
    -a stdout \
    -v $(pwd):$HOMEDIR \
    -w $HOMEDIR \
    $DOCKER_IMAGE \
    /bin/bash -ci $(full_container_cmd $@)
```

This script is bound to the 'acleancoder/imagemagick-full' image, but that can be changed by editing the variable at the top of the script.

What it basically does is:

- Create a user id and group within the *container* to match the user who executes the script from the *host OS*.
- Mounts the current working directory of the *host OS* (using docker volumes) into *home directory* for the user we create within the executing *docker container*.
- Sets the tmp directory as the working directory for the *container*.
- Passes any arguments that are passed to the script, which will then be executed by the '*/bin/bash*' of the executing *docker container*.

Now I am able to run the *ImageMagick/Ffmpeg* commands against files on my host OS. For example, say I want to convert an image *MyImage.jpeg* into a *PNG* file, I could now do the following:

```bsh
$ cd ~/MyImages
$ ls
  MyImage.jpeg
$ dockermagick convert MyImage.jpeg Foo.png
$ ls
  Foo.png MyImage.jpeg
```

I have also attached to the 'stdout' so I could run the ImageMagick identify command to get info on an image on my host, for e.g.:

```bsh
$ dockermagick identify MyImage.jpeg
  MyImage.jpeg JPEG 640x426 640x426+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 78.6KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

There are obvious dangers about mounting the current directory and allowing any arbitrary command definition to be passed along for execution.  But there are also many ways to make the script more safe/secure.  I am executing this in my own non-production personal environment, so these are not of highest concern for me.  But I would highly recommend you take the dangers into consideration should you choose to expand upon this script.  It's also worth me mentioning that this script doesn't take an OS X host into consideration.  The [make file](https://github.com/marmelab/make-docker-command/blob/master/Makefile) that I steal ideas/concepts from does take this into account, so you could extend this script to do so.

Another limitation to note is that I can only refer to files currently in the path for which I am executing the script.  This is because of the way I am mounting the volumes, so the following would not work:

```bsh
$ cd ~/MyImages
$ ls
  MyImage.jpeg
$ dockermagick convert ~/DifferentDirectory/AnotherImage.jpeg Foo.png
$ ls
  MyImage.jpeg
```

It's best just to go to the directory containing the image and execute against it directly.  Of course I am sure there are ways to get around this limitation too, but for me and my current needs, this will do.

Comment: This is a very neat concept, using docker as a way to isolate/ port command line tools!

Comment: This is excellent! Using it now, albeit adapted into Python and integrated into my own `docker` wrapper.

Comment: (The only problem is that it sets certain constraints on the Docker images you can use; namely, that they support all these commands as-is.)

Comment: Glad you went with Python, I did the same and was much happier with my scripts.  Not sure I am quite following you on the constraints issue you are raising, but if I am understanding correctly then I think it's reasonable to assume that you would need to set up the required docker images with the appropriate command line tools you require.  Cross communication of the running contains could be an interesting issue... :)

Comment: If you got "sudo command not found error". Use `echo "su $CONTAINER_USERNAME -c "` in execute_as_cmd() function.

Answer (score 7):

**Note**: *I answer here because, given the generic title, this Question pops up in google when you look for a solution to "Running app inside Docker as non-root user". Hope it helps those who are stranded here.*

With **Alpine** Linux you can create a system user like this:

```
RUN adduser -D -H -S -s /bin/false -u 1000 myuser
```

Everything in the `Dockerfile` after this line is executed with `myuser`.

`myuser` user has:

- no password assigned
- no *home* dir
- no login shell
- no *root* access.

This is from `adduser --help`:

```
-h DIR      Home directory
-g GECOS    GECOS field
-s SHELL    Login shell
-G GRP      Add user to existing group
-S          Create a system user
-D          Don't assign a password
-H          Don't create home directory
-u UID      User id
-k SKEL     Skeleton directory (/etc/skel)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: *This answer is given because many people looking for non-root usage will end up here. Beware, this does not address the issue that caused the problem, but is addressing the title and clarification to an answer given by @yegor256, which uses a non-root user inside the container. This answer explains how to accomplish this for non-debian/non-ubuntu use-case. This is not addressing the issue with volumes.*

On Red Hat-based systems, such as Fedora and CentOS, this can be done in the following way:

```
RUN adduser user && \
    echo "user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" | tee -a /etc/sudoers.d/user && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/user
```

In your Dockerfile you can run commands as this user by doing:

```
RUN su - user -c "echo Hello $HOME"
```

And the command can be run as:

```
CMD ["su","-","user","-c","/bin/bash"]
```

An example of this can be found here:
https://github.com/gbraad/docker-dev/commit/644c51002f4b8e6fe5bb745638542a4c3d908b16

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's issue where they did a chown on a volume that didn't apply to their final image. Sending the output of echo to a pipe to tee on a file seems odd, why not just append with a `>>`. And giving a user full sudo access to root undoes all the benefits of running the container as a non-root user.

Comment: This is related to an answer that was given by @yegor256. I was unable to clarify it in the comments section... I will include this in the answer to address

Comment: Updated information: http://gbraad.nl/blog/non-root-user-inside-a-docker-container.html